# how can I loop to update record in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops

I have database records to store page urls but we have problem in deployment the developer using localhost to store page filed in database because of that we end up with

```
http://localhost:8080/wow/page1.aspx  
http://localhost:8080/wow/page2.aspx
http://localhost:8080/wow/page3.aspx
```

just wondering can i write Tsql to loop throw record to remove the localhost from url and updating the new url

Comment: Updating the new URL to what? Should every row change `localhost` to something else, or will different rows have different URLs? Should the `:8080` stay? Also databases are designed to deal in *sets*. Most of the time, if you're thinking about looping, you need to re-think.

Comment: What do you want the final URL to look like?

Comment: What does this have to do with looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop, a simple UPDATE will do the trick. E.g.

```
UPDATE WEB_TABLE SET URL_FIELD = REPLACE(URL_FIELD, 'localhost:8080', 'www.mysite.com')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute a SQL update query using the replace method.

```
UPDATE [your table] SET [your field] = REPLACE([your field],'http://localhost:8080','')
```

That will update them all in one go.

OR, if you want to loop you could use a CURSOR

Comment: You're going to replace http://... with an empty string? And why would you ever "want to loop"?

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that desired result was to end up with links that would work in production... i.e. independent of the  domain the production site ends up on. The replace I advised would do that.

Possible cause could be WYSIWYG editor content that came from development environment. Proper solution would be to use non-domain specific links to begin with... but hey, it's an imperfect world.

Looping? Not sure... maybe there needs to be some other analysis of the content before executing the update query.